# Is Clang a virus?

Tags: c, clang

I just started using clang. When is used the following command - `clang main.c` in cmd it gave an error.
 After 1-2 minutes my antivirus prompted that a.exe (The exe that clang compiled) is a threat! Then suddenly all programs on my system stop working. The only window I could see was the antivirus trying to disinfect. After sometime the progress freezed, I had to force stop my system and restart. Now the problem is I am scared to try again. Is there some problem in the command?
My program Simple) -

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
   /* I was just testing clang.*/
   printf("HI!);
   
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Which operating system?  Which version of `clang`?  Which antivirus package?  In any case, this type of question goes on [Super User](https://superuser.com).

Comment: Windows. 11.0.0. Kaspersky.

Comment: no, it's not a virus. What happened was due to something else. What did your program look like

Comment: I have edited the quesion. The program is there.

Comment: I took risk and tried again. The program worked. But the antivirus still gave a error of trojan

Comment: If I recall correct, some anti-viruses may recognize new unknown executable files as threats. Sometimes, mistakenly. In any case, clang is not a virus, if it's a real clang.

Comment: Generally speaking, clang is a reputable C compiler. That said, we have know way to know if the file `clang` on your computer is/contains a virus.

Comment: i Installed from official llvm site [Here] (https://clang.llvm.org/)

Comment: Your source has a typo, the string misses the closing quotation mark. -- AV software is known to produce false positives, ask Kaspersky how to work around.

Comment: Attributes of a virus: prevents you from using your computer as you like, slows everything down, accesses the Internet without your permission, prevents you from closing down the process, pretends to be something helpful while it's actively harmful. Conclusion: your anti-virus software is a virus.

Comment: While it's technically possible for the copy of CLANG on your computer to have been infected with a virus; it's much more likely that the anti-virus software is a dodgy joke (e.g. seeing "executable not signed with publisher's digital signature" and falsely assuming that it's a risk without caring if it actually is or not).

Answer (score 2):

Back in the days, hackers appended their malware by injecting it at the end of an executable then exploited something in the program to make it jump to that address. Therefore anti-virus software traditionally looks for changes in executable sizes. This naturally happens very frequently to the executable you are generating while programming it. So the anti-virus thinks you are creating a virus when you are changing the executable size by appending more code.

Therefore you can't use anti-virus software while programming - they are too blunt and dumb to understand what to do on a computer used for programming. I recommend to uninstall it or at least find a way to disable it.

Comment: Instead of disabling the anti-virus software on Windows, I would recommend using a different operating system for programming, such as linux, in a vm.

Comment: @chqrlie Doesn't work well for modern programs that have an actual GUI though. It must usually be compiled for Windows.

Comment: Hi, I unistalled the clang 11 version and installed the latest 13. And now the executables are not a virus. Thanks.